# SQL Query: Better Option for Returns First and Last Names with Spaces?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find a list of Customers who's FirstName OR LastName Contains an Empty space in the middle of the name. Here is the current query I am using.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCustomers
WHERE FirstName LIKE '% %'
       OR
      LastName LIKE '% %'
```

Update***  Basically I want to return data that does NOT have spaces to the left or right of the name only somewhere in the middle of the name.

Comment: And? What is your problem? That should do what you want...

Comment: @Milney updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean: return every name with spaces in the middle no matter if there is whitespace at the beginning or at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tblCustomers
WHERE
    TRIM(FirstName) LIKE '% %'
    OR
    TRIM(LastName) LIKE '% %'
```

Comment: How would this work? '     Jo hn     ' would get matched even though it's got leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @Error_2646 As you read it word by word from the OP, you are right. But I think the whitespaces at the beginning or at the end do not matter. It is all about the whitespace in the middle of the name. Andy can tell ...

Answer (score 1):

This should work, tag your DBMS though and check the docs for whether it's length function considers trailing spaces. I'm assuming SQL server and using datalength.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tblCustomers
WHERE (
    FirstName LIKE '% %'
    AND DATALENGTH(TRIM(FirstName)) = DATALENGTH(FirstName)
      )
    OR
    (
    LastName LIKE '% %'
    AND DATALENGTH(TRIM(LastName)) = DATALENGTH(LastName)
      );
```